# How to return the second item of the nth pair in a given list (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am wondering how to return the 2nd item of the nth pair in a given list. So we have

```
nth :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int
```

So if we input

```
nth 3 [(2,0),(1,4),(3,8)]
```

it should return 8 as this is the 2nd item of the 3rd pair.

This is what I have got so far, it doesn't work...

```
nth :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int
nth n [] = error "??"
nth 0 (x:xs) = error "??"
nth n (x:xs)
  |n > 0 && n < length (x:xs) = -- dont know what to put here
```

Can anyone assist?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: You'll want to check for two cases: What should you return if n is 1? What should you do if n is greater than 1?

Answer (score 2):

To fill in from what you have so far:

```
nth :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int
nth n [] = error "??"
nth 0 (x:xs) = snd x
nth n (x:xs)
  |n > 0 && n < length (x:xs) = nth (n-1) xs
```

(The `snd` function simply returns the second element of a pair)

However, you might try simply combining the `!!` and `snd` functions like this:

```
nth' :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int
nth' n xs = snd (xs !! n)
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to use 1-based indices. That is why the second case has an `error` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *recurse* on the *tail* of the list. You thus call the function again, but with `n-1`, and the tail of the list. As base case, we then check if the index is the case, we return the second element of this the  case, we return the second element of that tuple. an implementation that does not uses any builtin functions, could look like:

```
nth :: Int -> [(a, b)] -> b
nth _ [] = error "Index too large"
nth n _ | n <= 0 = error "Index too small"
nth 1 ((_, b):_) = b
nth n (_: xs) = nth (n-1) xs
```

But actually we can use the `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`, `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` and `snd :: (a, b) -> b` funstions, and thus write it like:

```
nth n = snd . (!! (n-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first break the problem into small parts and then work, test each part; you finally put them back together.

```
-- 1. Pair each element with an index starting from 1   -> [(Int, (Int, Int))]
-- 2. Find the nth-index element                        -> Maybe (Int, (Int, Int))
-- 3. Get the 2nd element of the second element         -> Int
```

put the above 3 together you get:

```
import Data.Foldable(find)

nth :: Int -> [(Int, Int)] -> Int
nth n = get2ndIn2nd . findByIndex n
  where    
    findByIndex n xs = find ((n ==) . fst) $ zip [1..] xs 
    get2ndIn2nd p
        | (Just (_, (_, b))) <- p = b
        | otherwise = error "Boo!"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nth2nd :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> Int
nth2nd n xs = head [b | (i,(_,b)) <- zip [1..] xs, i==n]
```

is all you need. Of course this function is partial, i.e. if `n` is greater than the list's length it'll cause an error, and if `n` is less than 1 it'll try to traverse the whole list needlessly, and then cause an error (or loop indefinitely if the list is infinite).

This isn't usually considered to be a good thing. We usually prefer to explicate the possibility of failure with `Maybe`, thus making the function *total*:

```
import Data.Maybe

nth2ndMaybe :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> Maybe Int
nth2ndMaybe n xs = listToMaybe [b | (i,(_,b)) <- zip [1..] xs, i==n]
```

It'll still bomb on non-positive `n`s though. Adding a guard will help in handing this situation, preferably by returning `Nothing` explicitly:

```
nth2ndMaybe n xs 
          | n < 1     = Nothing
          | otherwise = ......
```